# Future-proofing wildcard pattern matches

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have:

```hs
data C = C Bool
```

and then define:

```hs
f :: C -> Int
f (C _) = 0
```

This is perfectly good, except the match against the underscore is a bit dangerous. It completely ignores the type of the field. That is, if I change the data type later on like this:

```hs
data C = C Int
```

the function `f` still type-checks just fine.

This is precisely the situation I'd like to avoid: I'd like to get a warning for the definition of `f`, in the sense that it is way too permissive with regard to changes to the fields of the datatype `C`.

Note that if I act defensively, I can do:

```hs
f' :: C -> Int
f' (C (_ :: Bool)) = 0
```

This is nice since if I change the field of `C` to contain a field with a different type later on, I get a nice error message from GHC. While this is exactly what I'd like, it'd be even better if I can get GHC to warn me about this possible pitfall if I forget to be defensive in the above sense. That is, if I pass, say, `-warn-permissive-patternmatch`, or annotate the data-type `C` in some way to require more checking, I'd like to get a warning.

While the above is a contrived example, you can imagine this being useful in a real-life scenario, with a data-type with many constraints and many fields. (As in a compiler intermediate-representation for instance.) When writing functions over these types, we usually simply put an `_` for fields we don't care about for a given function. But if we later decide to change the field-type to something different, we'd like to review all these wildcard pattern-matches to make sure the necessary changes are done. It would be nice if GHC told us there's a possible "maintenance" headache in these cases, and the proper solution would be to put the extra annotation as in `f'` above. Obviously, this should be opt-in, and most likely on a per-data-type-declaration, instead of at the module-level. (Though the latter can be made to work I suppose.)

Is there some trick one can use in GHC to get a similar effect today? Can this be implemented by a compiler plugin? Or, does this belong to GHC proper, and thus will have to be implemented directly by the compiler? How useful would it be for others? What other mechanisms do you deploy to avoid such maintenance issues for long-running projects? I'd especially appreciate feedback from a long-term code maintenance perspective.

### Update

Thanks for the comments so far. I do agree that it'd be impossible to get something 100%-rock solid, since GHC has no way of foretelling what we intended nor it sees "previous" versions of the code. To make this more precise, what I'm really looking for is if I write a function like`f` above, GHC should tell me that I should annotate the wildcard to avoid possible changes to the ignored value. That is, it essentially would ask me to write `f'` instead, which is defensive to this sort of long-term code maintenance issues. (As @amalloy pointed out, there's no "perfect" solution here, but I think an opt-in warning would be nice and can help in large/long-running projects.)

An oft-quoted "strength" of Haskell is that maintenance is easier: Change the data-type and let GHC walk you through all the pieces of code you have to modify. This is one case where that promise fails, unfortunately. I'm trying to figure out a "trick" (or a new feature in GHC) that'd make this strength of Haskell go further with respect to changes of this sort.

Comment: I don't see the problem. It doesn't ignore the type of the field; it safely assumes that the value of `C` is created correctly. If it doesn't use the value, the type that someone else *did* have to worry about doesn't mater. If it does use the value, you'll get the type error you want.

Comment: That's precisely the point. For this incarnation of `f`, there's no problem. But if I change the field type later on, I might have to modify it. That's why I'm looking for a way to get a "warning" in the super-paranoid mode, if you'd like to call it that.

Comment: Can you define what you want more precisely? Specifically, what is it exactly about function `f` that is "wrong" when `C` contains a `Bool`, but "correct" when `C` contains an `Int`?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin There's nothing wrong with `f`. The point is, how can we program defensively so we get a notification if the underlying representation changes. I added an update which hopefully clarifies the intent.

Comment: Ok, so if the trigger you want is "when something changes", it means you're looking for the compiler to have some sort of memory about the "previous" compilation, and then compare the "current" one to it, and warn you about differences?

Comment: No, I'm not expecting GHC to look at "previous" versions. Just seeking methodology advice (or GHC feature) that can help with this sort of maintenance issues. (i.e., when I annotate `_ :: Bool` in the pattern match, I protect myself against the field-type change to a certain degree. I'd like GHC to tell me if I fail to protect myself in this way.

Comment: I see what you are asking. It seems more like you are misusing the wildcard (changing the type shouldn't suddenly make you care about the value if you didn't care about it before), but I don't have a better suggestion to post as an answer.

Comment: @chepner That'd be ideal indeed, i.e., not changing the type once you commit to something. But in a long running project, these things inevitably change. Especially when multiple developers are involved, as is the usual case in the industry.

Comment: I'm not saying you can't change the type, just that you shouldn't use "ignore the value" both to really ignore the value and as a placeholder for a value you might care about later if the type changes.

Comment: These inevitably arise from a change in what the constructor means. In my use case, it was originally simply a list of numbers that the function didn’t care. In the new version, the constructor changed to carry a list of the data type defined, like a tree branch. Obviously a semantic change that the function no longer correctly handled. I wish I could say this is bad design. Alas, in a long running project, such changes are almost inevitable. Maybe the right thing to do is to rename the constructor itself.

Comment: Put me on team "you don't want to hear about changes in the underlying representation if the code can still handle it."

Answer (score 3):

I think the goal here is a bit fuzzy. Do you want the compiler to warn you every time you ignore a field in a pattern-match? In that case you can stop using `_` altogether, since its purpose is to tell the compiler you are ignoring a field on purpose and to stop warning you. Instead turn on `-Wunused-matches` and replace all your underscores with variables.

But I don't think you really want that. You want something like `_` which will not issue any warnings until you make some change to the type being matched on. I don't think this is something GHC can help you with. Even in your contrived example, the workaround you have (adding a type annotation) doesn't really work. It's fine if you imagine changing the definition of C, but what if you changed the definition of Bool instead? Then the type annotation would still be correct, so you'd get no warning, but your code has still become wrong. Of course in real life we don't change Bool, but a similar problem arises with types you do own. Here is a somewhat more realistic example:

```
data Location
data TrafficLightColor = Red | Green
data TrafficLight = TrafficLight Location TrafficLightColor

canSpeedUp :: TrafficLight -> Bool
canSpeedUp (TrafficLight loc color) = case (farAway loc, color) of
  (True, _) -> True
  (False, Red) -> False
  (False, _) -> True
```

In some of the case bodies, you ignore the color with `_`. So these lines are examples of locations you'd like GHC to help you with, by somehow alerting you anytime the type of `color` changes. But this is not enough: even if `color :: TrafficLightColor` remains true, this code can become wrong if someone adds `Yellow` to the `TrafficLightColor` definition. The first case is still right, because you really want to ignore any faraway light, but the last case is wrong because you should slow down for yellow lights too.

What I'm getting at is that every usage of `_` in any context can potentially become wrong, and GHC has no way to know if a given change to your codebase has made one of these `_`s wrong or not. It doesn't get a diff between the old version of your code and the new one, so it can't warn you, hey, this new value is falling into the `_` case, did you mean to do something different? All it can do is see that you have an unused variable, but you explicitly said you don't care about its value by using `_`, so it won't bother you. If you want a different behavior, you have to give up the convenience of `_`.

Comment: I agree that something that works 100% perfectly isn't possible, since what "perfect" means will depend on the particular change introduced later on. All I really want is for GHC to tell me that I should be annotating the wildcard, in case I haven't already done so. (Surely this won't always help, but I think it'll go a long ways in terms of maintenance.) –